# Every action performed and tells by sound

Tags: 14.04, sound

Whenever I press a key, I hear it through my speakers, so when I press <kbd>A</kbd> I hear A, and when I press <kbd>B</kbd> I hear B and so on. When I hover on any application it tells me which application it is. Every action it tells by sound.

Can any one please tell me how to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 4):

You might have enabled Screen Reader accidentally.

To solve, try to press `Alt+Super+S` to disable it.

If it still sounds for every action, go to System Settings --> Universal Access --> Seeing and turn off Screen Reader.

[image: Turn off Screen Reader by clicking the ON slider.]

Comment: because of the screen reader, my `home` and `end` buttons were not working properly, I did not even know this setting was enabled until I connected headphones to the pc, eventually everything got back to normal, thanks